# Photo is not changing according to the chosen option

Tags: javascript, html, click, product

I'm creating a product page with a yt tutorial and unfortunately the code doesn't work. I am trying to do that if someone clicks on the thumbnail of the photo under the main photo, photo is changing according to the option. I hope it make sense, standard product page feature. Unfortunately it's not working, tried pretty anything I could think of. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?
Thank you in advance for your time

```js
let MainImg = document.getElementById("MainImg");
let smallimg = document.getElementsByClassName("small-img-col");

smallimg[0].onclick = function() {
  MainImg.src = smallimg[0].src;
};
smallimg[1].onclick = function() {
  MainImg.src = smallimg[1].src;
};
smallimg[2].onclick = function() {
  MainImg.src = smallimg[2].src;
};
smallimg[3].onclick = function() {
  MainImg.src = smallimg[3].src;
};
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="/logo.png" class="logo" alt="" /></a>

  <div>
    <ul id="navbar" style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0">
      <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li id="lg-bag">
        <a href="cart.html"><i class="fi fi-rr-shopping-cart"></i></a>
      </li>

      <a href="#" id="close"><i class="fi fi-rr-cross-small"></i></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile">
    <i class="fi fi-rr-shopping-cart"><a href="cart.html"></a></i>
    <i id="bar" class="fi fi-rr-menu-burger"></i>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="prodetails" class="section-p1">
  <div class="single-pro-image">
    <img src="/f1.jpeg" width="100%" id="MainImg" alt="" />

    <div class="small-img-group">
      <div class=" small-img-col"><img src="/f1.jpeg" width="100%" /></div>
      <div class="small-img-col"><img src="/f2.jpeg" width="100%" /></div>
      <div class="small-img-col"><img src="/f3.jpeg" width="100%" /></div>
      <div class="small-img-col"><img src="/f6.jpeg" width="100%" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="single-pro-details">
    <h6>Home - T-shirt</h6>
    <h4>Men's Fasion</h4>
    <h2>$139.00</h2>
    <select>
      <option>Select Size</option>
      <option>S</option>
      <option>M</option>
      <option>L</option>
      <option>XL</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" value="1" />
    <button class="normal">Add To Card</button>
    <h4>Product Details</h4>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span
        >
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I changed the tags, note that Java and JavaScript are completely different languages. Is your code exacly as in the question? If so, you must put the JavaScript code inside `<script>{Your code here}</script>` tags

Comment: Open up the developer console and see if there is an error message.

Comment: Pretty east to spot when you open up the debugger the images you are loading are `https://example.com/undefined` because you bound the click on the DIV and not the IMG. The div does not have a src attribute. The class should be on the image and not the div.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the issue here is in the way you are trying to access the src for the images using `getElementsByClassName` . You can try to do it like below:

```
let MainImg = document.getElementById("MainImg");
let smallimgs = document.querySelectorAll(".small-img-col img");

smallimgs.forEach(function (smallimg) {
  smallimg.addEventListener("click", function () {
    MainImg.src = this.src;
  });
});
```

Doing this, you can iterate through all the smallimages and add an event listener to them

Comment: Nice catch! The op actually targeted the `div` elements instead of the `img`, this should be the key to solve the problem

Comment: Or the OP moves the class to the image and keeps their code the same.